# After creating a signed release build with Eclipse how do I run the release APK?

Tags: android, proguard

I'd like to run the release APK to make sure it runs ok with Proguard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You install it using [adb](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html):

```
adb install your.signed.apk
```

Comment: The package, signed with the debug certificate should be removed before installing release version.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I needed, just had no idea how to get there.